# jQuery events not attached on page load

Tags: jquery

I have a problem that drives me crazy.
Here is my code:

```
<a href="#" class="panel-minimize">
     <i class="fa fa-chevron-up text-white"></i>
</a>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.panel-minimize').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $target = $(this).parent().parent().parent().next('.panel-body');
        if ($target.is(':visible')) { 
            $('i', $(this)).removeClass('fa-chevron-up').addClass('fa-chevron-down'); 
        }
        else { 
            $('i', $(this)).removeClass('fa-chevron-down').addClass('fa-chevron-up'); 
        }
        $target.slideToggle();
    });
    $(".user_details").colorbox({ iframe: true, innerWidth: 425, innerHeight: 344 });
});
```

Very simple and supposed to run, but it doesn't...
I added an alert on the `$(document).ready` and it shows the alert, but the events are not working.
If i take the code inside the `$(document).ready` and put it the console in chrome it works fine, but for some unknown reason it doesn't work by itself when the page loads.

Comment: how are you adding elements `.panel-minimize`

Comment: it is hard coded in my HTML

Comment: Error in console??? Are you able to replicate issue online?

Comment: are you adding markup dynamically?

Comment: `$(this).parent().parent().parent()` exists? Why don't you try closest()?

Comment: There are no errors in the console, in fact if I take the js code and put it in the console in chrome it works fine

Comment: So i guess you need to delegate click event because of `colorbox` plugin. Replace `$('.panel-minimize').click(function (e) {...});` inside document ready handler by `$(".user_details").on('click', '.panel-minimize', function(e){...});`

Comment: I tried to remove the colorbox completely, and it still doesn't work...

Comment: @LiranFriedman If you are unable to show us an example online replicating your issue, how can we help you more?...

Comment: I don't know how to replicate it online...
I tried using $(".user_details").on('click', '.panel-minimize', function(e){...}); and it still doesn't work

Comment: And `$(document).on('click', '.panel-minimize', function(e){...});`?  Isn't `'.panel-minimize'` inside an iframe (because of colorbox option)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68395/discussion-between-liran-friedman-and-a-wolff).

Comment: If I use an onclick in the a tag like this `<a onclick="someFunc()"></a>` it also works fine. the problem is only when I use $(documet).ready. But if I put an alret inside the $(documet).ready it shows the alert, but it doesn't show it from the click event. This is some crazy situation I have never seen in all of my years as a programmer...

Answer (score -1):

In my view your code is unable to find $target. Please try below code :

```
var $target = $(this).parent().parent().parent().nextAll('.panel-body');
```

check if $target.length is not 0. Try another way to target $('.panel-body').

Comment: didn't work...
Even if I put alert("a") inside the `$('.panel-minimize').click(function (e) {...})` it douesn't fire the alert...